# size and the type of object created by the vector string constuctor in C++

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

```
int numRows = 5;
string s ="hellohi";
vector<string> rows(min(numRows, int(s.size())));
```

I think it is using the fill constructor. 
 https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

 
but I don't know it creates a vector of NULL string or a vector of an empty string ? 
And what is the size of the NULL ?

And what is the size of the empty string?  1 bytes ("/0"char) ?

Comment: What is a null string?

Comment: It creates "a vector of an empty string". You declare a vector of strings, not a vector of pointers to `string`.

Comment: There are no nullable objects in C++. You need an additional level of indirection to have them (see `std::optional` call template). The size of a `std::string` object is always the same, it is known at the compile time and doesn't depend on string contents.

Comment: In my case , the min size is 5 , so the size of the empty string vector is 1 bytes *5 ?@Evg

Comment: It looks like you do not understand the difference between `rows.size` and `sizeof rows`. `size` returns the count of elements (5). `sizeof` returns the number of bytes `rows` is made of, which is the same regardless of the number of elements (`rows` holds the address of elements, not the elements).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you're using will create empty strings. For example you can check with:

```
// check the number of entries in rows, should be 5
std::cout << rows.size() << std::endl;

// check the number of characters in first string, should be 0
std::cout << rows[0].size() << std::endl;

// now the size should be 11, since there are 11 entries
rows[0] = "hello world";
std::cout << rows[0].size() << std::endl;
```

I believe the size of NULL is implementation defined, you could find it with:

```
std::cout << sizeof(nullptr) << std::endl;
```

I get 8 as the size (which is 64 bits)

Similar to the nullptr, the size of an empty string is probably also implementation defined, you can find it like:

```
std::string test_string;
std::cout << sizeof(test_string) << "\n";
std::cout << test_string.size() << "\n"; // should be 0 since the string is empty

test_string = "hello world"; // it doesn't matter how long the string is, it's the same size
std::cout << sizeof(test_string) << "\n";
std::cout << test_string.size() << "\n"; // should be 11 since the string has data now
```

I get 32 bytes for the size. The reason the size of the string doesn't change is due to how it works behind the scenes, instead of storing data  (most of the time) it only stores a pointer to the data (which is always a fixed size).

Comment: `sizeof(nullptr)` doesn't actually tell you anything about the size of pointers. `nullptr` is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`, which is not a pointer type (it implicitly converts to any pointer type)